# How to use web service Soap Client method with Xamarin

Tags: web-services, soap-client, xamarin-studio

I have added my web service Url to my application through the steps of "Add Web Reference" with the name of "SOAPNyd" in Xamarin Studio

Now I need to connect my web Methods, I see my web referenced methods under Web Service folder but can not connect to them and need know how to call , use my methods.
Could anyone show me one example with while loop to write down its all data to the Console please. Thank you.

here is one of my methods which returns all brands that I have at Data Base first value is empty second value is my pasword dont worry about parameters

```
public string getMarkalarlist(string s, string key) {
    getMarkalarlistRequest1 inValue = new getMarkalarlistRequest1();
    inValue.s = s;
    inValue.key = key;
    getMarkalarlistResponse1 retVal = ((WebDBServicesHttpGet)(this)).getMarkalarlist(inValue);
    return retVal.@string;
}
```

a piece of my need
http://www.nullskull.com/a/10476774/consuming-web-services-using-xamarin.aspx

Comment: you saying that how to consume your service on cient side?

Comment: I try to say ; I have added my web Serice Url to my application with reference, now I need to reach my methods  like

 CalculatorWebService service = new CalculatorWebService ();

CalculatorWebServiceSoap soap = service.getPort(CalculatorWebServiceSoap.class); but dont know the right connection rules

Comment: yes thats what we call consuming of webservice

Comment: `using (var objCalculatorWebService  = new CalculatorWebService Client())
            { // your code 
}`

Comment: plz format your code